# Symfony 1.4 default query condition possible with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony1, symfony-1.4

We added a new column to the database called is_active and now have to modify the whole code in Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine.. to query just Entries which match this condition.

I know that in Yii there is a defaultScope which is applied everytime automatically when you query the database. Is there something like this also in Symfony.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could have created getWhateverScopeQuery() in your ModelTable class, and now set the condition there, but now it's little late. But better late than never ;)